# So, how do we all feel about Hats?

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange celebrates the winter holidays by having a "hat" event known as "Winter Bash" which starts this year on December 19th and lasts about two weeks. Doing actions on the sites can earn you a hat you can use to decorate your avatar. [Here's a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats) of the hats from last year as an example.

Some of the hats are easy to get, others are difficult, secret hats.

As a site, we can choose to opt out if there is a large number of users who do not want to earn hats.

So, do we want hats on Arts & Crafts?

As a note, if you do not want to participate as an individual, you can always opt out network-wide by clicking on an opt out button that will be available everywhere. It reads "I Hate Hats".

[image: Example of Hats from 2015]

[More info about hats.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/01/Winter-Bash-2015-Hats-Off/)

Answer (score 11):

### Yes!

Hats are fun! Plus, making hats is even on-topic!

Comment: Maybe that's one of the secret hats: ASK HOW TO CRAFT A HAT.

Comment: @Erica if it's not, it should be for next year! That being said... it would sure give us a lot of dupe questions to moderate.

Comment: Might as well go for it. If people don't want to participate they do not have to. Enabling it will give people the choice if they want to opt out.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, we don't actually have to opt in. If we don't do anything, we get hats :P I don't know why we wouldn't do it but we thought we'd ask. I think only one or two sites ever opt out.

Comment: @Catija I more meant that I am pretty sure we can do this and not all users are forced to use them so the individual can choose not to use them.

Comment: @Erica We need a [tag:hats] tag **now**.

Comment: @haykam [Your wish is my command](http://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hats).